# Accessing Environment Variable set by Jenkins in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jenkins, environment-variables, create-react-app

I have added a key `user_Name` in jenkins deployer.
Now I am trying to read the same key using the `process.env.user_Name` in react application but it is giving me `undefined`.

I also tried with prefix `REACT_APP_` but it is still giving me the same thing.

So my question is how can I access the jenkins environment variable in React App.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should let Jenkins remake your .env file, and then rebuild.
So you can read it when the server construction phase